# Changing width/height to a CSS rotated div triggers top/left reposition

Tags: css, webkit, matrix, rotatetransform

I have a `<div>` that its rotated 66 deg with `-webkit-transform(rotate66)`. When I am performing a resize, width or height, the div seems to change his top/left coordinates. The actual `left/top` CSS proprieties do not change though. I think that there is something going wrong in the transform matrix.

Is there any way of making the rotated `<div>` "stay still" on a `width/height` resize? On resize should be a left and top prop applied to counter this movement but I can't seems to find the right proportions.

You can see the test here (Webkit Only): http://jsbin.com/iqezoj/4/edit

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a `-webkit-transform-origin` as well to control *where* the origin of the transformation. [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/-moz-transform-origin) quite good on this subject.

**Edit** `-webkit-transform-origin: 100px 50px;` moves the point to the middle of the `<div>` in your example. The default value is `50% 50%` which will change depending on the height and width of the `<div>` which explains why the position was shifting.

Comment: Updated with an explanation to why it is broken without specifying the origin.

Comment: The only problem is that after resize in order to perform a new rotate from center you need to recalculate and set the new origin point in px according the the new width and height. This makes the div jump.

Comment: Do you have an example of what is not working correctly? I _think_ I understand that you want to keep the shape anchored to a single point which can be rotated around and re-sized. Actually it might be better if you ask that as another question? It sounds like a subsequent problem.

Comment: Exactly, I want to be able to rotate and resize it without making it jumpy. Rotation should happen from center. Sorry I do not have an example right now. Thank you